# Should I say "It's better for me to talk BY / ON / IN English"

Tags: prepositions

What's better for you as a native English speakers?
If for example you see someone who knows 2 languages, but you understand English only. Then you want to talk the language that's considered understandable for you. Here are the options:

> "It's better for me to talk **by / on / in** English"

or to say simply

> "It's better for me to talk English" (without any prepositions)

Comment: One speaks (or writes) English. One does not talk English.

Comment: 'Talk *in* English' is ok. 'By' or 'on', no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context -  the correct sentence is: "It's better to talk **in** English".

You can talk *on* English - but that means you are talking about the English language

You can also talk *by* English - but that would indicate you are talking next to a person called English.

The reason why you can't say "talk *by* English" to mean talk using English is because English is not a physical tool you use to do the physical action of talking, unlike a pickaxe for mining (mine by pickaxe) or an telephone for talking over long distances (talk by telephone).

However, you can "Communicate by English" - because communication is not a physical action, and English is a tool for Communication.

Comment: `+1` Personally, I'd delete the second paragraph and tidy up a touch, but still an excellent answer.